# Excel VBA: Check checkbox on webpage based on inner text

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

I know that there are few question on how to check checkbox but couldn't the situation I am dealing with.

Here is the sample of webpage code:

```html
<tr class="odd">
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="device_id" value="3896">
  </td>
  <td>text1</td>
  <td>text2</td>
  <td>xxx</td>
  <td>
    Good
  </td>
  <td>
   </td></tr>

<tr class="odd">
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="device_id" value="3955">
  </td>
  <td>text3</td>
  <td>text4</td>
  <td>xxx</td>
  <td>
    Good
  </td>
  <td>
</td></tr>
```

This is just a sample, there are hundreds of "entries" like this.

I have a macro that opens a page and navigates where it should. It is also not a problem to check checkbox based on value, which is an ID assigned to text1/text2, text3/text4, etc. internally by a database. Problem is that I do not know that ID and all I know is text1/text2, text3/text4, etc.

What I am struggling with is, how to check that checkbox if I know only those texts? I know there is a way how to match texts with and ID and then use that ID to check checkbox but I have no idea how to do that match. Any help will be appreciated :-)

Thank you.

Comment: What is 3955, what do text1/2 etc mean, can you elaborate, or are you saying query the database and find the id of say text1 which would be 3955?

Comment: 3955 is random ID assigned by database. Database is a list of devices, each has name (text1) and IP (text2). There are hundreds of devices, each has one "tr" section in webpage code. In an example there is a code for 2 devices. I need to select e.g. 5 devices that are in database, check a checkbox next to that device and let database do something. I don't know ID as it is internally assigned. I know only hostname and IP. I need to get that ID based on the text1 or text2 (text3 and 4 are for the second device, etc.) and then use that ID in a vba code to check checkbox.

Comment: you need to look at using html controls library, you haven't actually posted your VBA so cant comment, but I'd use a collection populated using `document.getelementsbytagname("TABLE")(0).getElementsByTagName("TD")` and work through that collection in steps of 2 to get the ID that way.

Comment: I think I've solved it. I will post code later for reference. What you've proposed actually helped me.  Thank you Nathan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me:

Find in which "tr" section hostname or IP is and then just read the ID value.

```vb
' find tr and ID
For i = 1 To 5000
    checkdevX = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("tr")(i).innerText
    If InStr(checkdevX, "text2") Then
        idvalue = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("tr")(i).getElementsByTagName("td")(0). _
                    getElementsByTagName("input")(0).getAttribute("value")
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

' check checkbox
Set CheckBox = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each idnumber In CheckBox
        If (idnumber.getAttribute("value") = idvalue) Then
            idnumber.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```